# how to select the items that I keep a user by means of a multiselect and bring those same data to update them with another multiselect in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

hello friends I need help ... I have a multiselect that keeps several types of products that a user sells (it is a relationship of many to many) and I made a pivot table...So what I need is that when I update the data, it shows me the same data that I select to multiselect

this is my controller with the query to the pivot table

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $usuarios = User::find($id);
    $categorias = CategoriaComercial::all();
    $productos = TipoProducto::all();
    $pivot = ProductosUsers::where('user_id',$id)->get();
    $roles = Role::whereIn("id",[2,3])->get();
    $paises= Paises::all();

    return view('admin.usuarios.edit',compact('usuarios','categorias','productos', 'paises','roles','pivot'));
}
```

this is my model of the pivot table

```
 public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id');
}

public function productos()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','tipo_producto_id');
}
```

and this is the multiselect in my view

```
<select class="selectpicker form-control" id="select" multiple="multiple" name="tipo_producto[]"  required>
                <option value="">Seleccione productos...</option>
                @foreach($pivot as $p)
                  @foreach($productos as $producto)
                  <option {{ $p->tipo_producto_id == $producto->id? 'selected' : '' }} value="{{ $producto->id }}"> {{ $producto->nombre_tipo_producto }}</option>
                  @endforeach
                @endforeach
              </select>
```

the problem with this is that I repeat the data ... and if I delete some data this is only added (repeated) to the pivot table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing one foreach loop and changing the condition for 'selected' fixes it:

```
<select class="selectpicker form-control" id="select" multiple="multiple" name="tipo_producto[]"  required>
    <option value="">Seleccione productos...</option>
    @foreach($productos as $producto)
    <option {{ $pivot->contains('tipo_producto_id', $producto->id)? 'selected' : '' }} value="{{ $producto->id }}"> {{ $producto->nombre_tipo_producto }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

---

Aside from that, are you sure you want ProductosUsers to have a Model for itself? With a `belongsToMany` you can let Laravel handle the logic for the pivot table.

Comment: Friend, it worked for me ... thank you very much ... if you're right, I should not put a relationship on that model

Comment: only now I have another problem ... when unchecking an item previously selected ... this is not deleted .. is more vulve to enter the data ... for example ... a user marks 2 products burgers and soda. ..then when you edit that (uncheck soda and only hamburgers remain) you add hamburgers twice ... you have some idea of how to solve that ... thank you very much for your help.

Comment: On a many-to-many relationship the `sync()` could be used, but in your case you could delete all records in the ProductosUsers table for the user and re-add the ones selected.

Comment: exactly what I did ... delete what the user selected previously and insert the new selection...thank you very much for your help friend